# Setting up power to 3 buildings

Tags: transformer, electrical-panel

I am going to be digging a trench to the new future location of a transformer behind my shed. The transformer will be ~15 feet behind the shed and is in an approved location by my utility.

My question is that I would like this transformer to have a service conductor that runs to the back of the shed where I will mount a meter and a panel there.
I would like a small branch circuit or two inside the shed for lights and power outlets. This same transformer is going to power two other buildings: an ADU with a big garage on one side and a very large ag shop on the other side.

I would like a service conductor to run after the meter, but before the shed panel to each of those two buildings.
The service coming in will be 320 amps, the shed only needs maybe 40-50 amps, the ADU and ag shop each need at least 200 amps.
How do you recommend I set this up?

Comment: Who's your electric utility?  Can you get us an idea of what loads are actually in the ag shop, as well as the square footage each of the shed and the ADU, and what the ADU uses for heat/hot water?

Comment: Not an expert, so just a comment: Based on what I have seen in *lots* of other questions, 320A service will feed to 2 x 200A but trying to get more than 200A to any separate part of your property would be a bit complicated. If you can keep each building to 200A then it is relatively easy.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend Using a service panel meter base.

you can feed each location with the appropriate size breaker and feeder wires.

At each location a sub panel/ disconnect.

(my jurisdiction allows for the 1 location to have the disconnects and then external disconnects at the separate buildings are not required)

Just an FYI most utility transformers are fed with high voltage +12kv and require 4’ deep trenching along with a grounding loop around the pad with 2 driven rods or that is the requirement in several of the states I have worked and regulated by the utility.

Make sure to get an approved (by the utility) meter base panel I had a customer that wanted to use a cheep one that the utility would not connect to he purchased it even though I told him and when the utility came out and saw it they packed up and left I think it took 3 weeks before they would come back out and connect to a meter base they approved of.

Trying to save 150 this customer cost himself ~1k and 3 weeks, make sure to read the utility requirements as they are not the same as the NEC and they can and will say no to equipment they deem unsafe even if listed.

Comment: Yeah I don't think NEC has any requirement for external disconnects at secondary buildings, of course NEC 2020 requires the main disconnect be outdoors.  I agree, sounds like a "ranch panel" on the outside of the shed is a viable choice.